# Unable to use AWS Elastic Beanstalk with Docker to deploy Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, amazon-web-services, docker

I created a new environment in AWS Elastic Beanstalk, running Docker and import my Dockerrun.aws.json file however it does not deploy correctly. Here's my Dockerrun.aws.json file I upload - Can anyone tell me what's wrong with it?

```
{
"AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
"Image": {
    "Name": "wordpress"
},
"Ports": [
    {
        "ContainerPort": "80"
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker run file seems ok for me. The following worked fine:

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "wordpress",
    "Update": "false"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "ContainerPort": "80"
    }
  ],
  "Logging": "/var/log/nginx"
}
```

Make sure you have all EB env vars setup for MySQL connection. Otherwise it deploy will fail.